# "Argument is Length of Zero" on shiny + ggvis app

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I am building a shiny application that leverages dplyr and ggvis. I am able to get the application to launch, though I am getting an error message:

> Error in if (tag$name %in% c("area", "base", "br", "col", "command", "embed",  : 
>     argument is of length zero

Here is my **ui.R**:

```
`library(shiny)
library("ggvis")

shinyUI(fluidPage( 

titlePanel("Visual Stock Screener"),    

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  numericInput("MinMarketCap",
              "Min Market Cap (in Tens of Millions)",
              value = 10,
              min = 1,
              max = 60000),
  numericInput("MaxMarketCap",
               "Max Market Cap (in Tens of Millions)",
               value =  5000,
               min = 1,
               max = 60000),
  numericInput("MinDivYield",
              "Min Div Yield:",
              value = 0.04,
              min = 0,
              max = 1),                  

  numericInput("MaxDivYield",
              "Max Div Yield:",
              value = 0.14,
              min = 0,
              max = 1),

  numericInput("MinPayoutRatio",
               "Min Payout Ratio:",
               value = 0,
               min = 0),
  numericInput("MaxPayoutRatio",
               "Max Payout Ratio:",
               value = 0.4,
               min = 0),      

  numericInput("MinPriceBook",
               "Min Price/Book Ratio:",
               value = 0,
               min = 0),

  numericInput("MaxPriceBook",
               "Max Price/Book Ratio:",
               value = 3,
               min = 0),

  numericInput("MinPriceSales",
               "Min Price/Sales Ratio:",
               value = 0,
               min = 0),
  numericInput("MaxPriceSales",
               "Max Price/Sales Ratio:",
               value = 7,
               min = 0)      

  ),

mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(type="tab",
              tabPanel("Plot",ggvisOutput("visplot"),uiOutput("visplot_ui"))

              )


)
)))`
```

Here is my **server.R:**

```
`library(shiny)
library("ggvis")
library(dplyr)

#import file created by screener.R

final <- read.csv("final.csv") 

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram

shinyServer(function(input, output) {



output$visplot_ui <- renderUI({

allviz <- na.omit(final)
allviz <- filter(allviz, DivYield >= input$MinDivYield)
allviz <- filter(allviz, DivYield <= input$MaxDivYield)
allviz <- filter(allviz, PAYOUTRATIO >= input$MinPayoutRatio)
allviz <- filter(allviz, PAYOUTRATIO <= input$MaxPayoutRatio)
allviz <- filter(allviz, PriceBook >= input$MinPriceBook)
allviz <- filter(allviz, PriceBook <= input$MaxPriceBook)
allviz <- filter(allviz, PriceSales >= input$MinPriceSales)
allviz <- filter(allviz, PriceSales <= input$MaxPriceSales)
allviz <- filter(allviz, MarketCapinMil >= input$MinMarketCap)
allviz <- filter(allviz, MarketCapinMil <= input$MaxMarketCap)

allviz$id <- 1:nrow(allviz)

allviztip <- function(x) { if(is.null(x))return(NULL) 
                           row <- allviz[allviz$id == x$id,c(1,4,7,8,9,10)]
                           paste0(names(row),":",format(row),"  </div>",collapse="<br />")}

allviz[1:20,] %>% ggvis(x=~PriceBook,y=~DivYield,key:=~id,size=~MarketCap,shape=~PayoutCat,fill=~PriceSales) %>%
  layer_points() %>% add_tooltip(allviztip,"hover")  %>% bind_shiny("visplot","visplot_ui") 

})

})

`
```

I have gone through the previous stackoverflow questions related to this issue, and can confirm that some of the common causes are the not the case here:

1. I have a complete data set. final.csv has filtered out NA values (by way of the na.omit function).
2. I have removed each filter one by one, and the error still persists. so i don't believe it relates to filter naming or logic issues.
3. I took out the tooltip, and the error still persists.
4. The error does NOT occur outside of shiny, i.e. when I run the app locally in RStudio.

So I suspect there is some type of an issue with one of the functions R uses to render the HTML, which in turn leads me to believe there is some type of issue in ui.R. But other than that I'm frustrated and stuck.....any ideas?

Comment: can you replace your `final <- read.csv` line with a dput of a sample of your data?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error although not using ggvis at all.
I looked for common features between your code and mine who are generating the same error.
The issue, I guess, is that you are using a dynamic interface with uiOutput, and your `renderUI()` doesn't seem to set any output elements.
I didn't understand what is the role of `shiny_bind()`, but you can simply try by adding a simple html output, as `p("this is a test")`  at the end of your `renderUI()`.